# webpack /src outside root directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to specify a webpack entry point that's not located underneath my react project's root directory. Essentially I want to move my whole `/src` directory somewhere else so it can be shared. Here's my directory structure & webpack config:

```
monorepo/
|-- webpack-project/
|-- |-- package.json
|-- |-- webpack.config.json
|-- |-- old-src/
|-- |-- |-- index.js
|-- other-project
|-- |-- src/
|-- |-- |-- index.js
```

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: `${__dirname}/../other-project/src/index.js`
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(`${__dirname}/wwwroot`),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: '[name].js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
            { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
        ],
    },
}
```

When I specify `${__dirname}/old-src/index.js`, my project builds fine. When I specify the path to the other-project/src it has issues. The error I'm getting from the babel loader is at the first line of JSX in the entry file: `Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled`.

Does anyone know if what I'm trying to do is even possible, or if I should take a different approach?

Comment: You might have to set the `context` and `resolve.modules` configuration keys. Can you post your full webpack config?

Comment: I tried setting `context` too but it didn't change anything. Should I be setting it to the entry file `/src` directory, or my original project directory? I can look into `resolve.modules` too, I wasn't aware of that. I've got quite a large webpack config but I can try and add more of the relevant config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed by making 2 changes:

The first major one, I renamed by .babelrc to babel.config.js. More about why this fixes an issue [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration#whats-your-use-case).

I also added resolve.modules config to add the webpack-project's node_modules.

```
  ...

  resolve: {
      modules: [ path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules') ],
  },

  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `path` as dev dependency and use it:

```
const path = require('path');
...
app: path.join(__dirname, '../other-project/src/index.js'),
```